# Change default moderator dashboard "history" view to display weekly/daily stats, instead of monthly

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, moderation-history

[My favorite Oded](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140505/oded) kindly implemented a request I had a couple weeks ago to add a "weekly" ♦ moderator history summary to the moderator dashboard default page. It's a nice bit of information to see between the daily and monthly views. (There are also views for the quarter and all time)

I've noticed that the length of time to generate each of the views is correlated to the period being requested. Very roughly speaking, the daily view takes a second or so; weekly a couple seconds; monthly 4-5; and quarterly takes about 8. The "all time" view seems to time out; it returns an error page after a while.

*(Note: The times and error I describe above likely only apply to Stack Overflow, and perhaps a couple of the other higher-volume sites. Meta does not exhibit the same.)*

It seems that this may cause unnecessary load on the system, when that is our default entry into the ♦ moderator tools.

My proposal is to change the default view when loading `/admin` to be the weekly pr daily view, rather than the monthly. Alternatively, consider changing the `mod` link not to point to the history at all, but perhaps to the `/admin/links` page. This way we're not causing a somewhat costly query simply when popping into the ♦ tools.

(I know we can also enter the mod tools via the link to the flags, but sometimes I'm not looking to go to the flags - making *that too* an unnecessary set of queries)

Comment: Maybe SE could add some more caching to the mod dashboard to speed it up a bit ;-)

Comment: @MadScientist Thanks for giving me a twitch that won't go away until my doctor gives me some very specific medications... ;)

Comment: I'd prefer daily to be the default.

Comment: @TheGrinch Daily is a good option, yes. I think I'll refine this... Oh; and your choice is not at all related to wanting to give Moderators *less* for Festivus, is it??

Comment: Wouldn't that be a good problem?